# Asynchronous Client Socket, receive buffer data out of order

Tags: c#, ios, .net, sockets, asynchronous

So I have two things runner here.  An iPad application talking to a python script running on a linux server.  The python script is sending the iPad application data files of size ~1K bytes up to ~10K bytes. I'm having a very strange event that's occurring every once in a while (like maybe once every 100 or 200 tries).

[I modeled my Asynchronous Client Socket from this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  In the ReceiveCallback function that I've posted below, I receive data into my buffer like this:

```
string stuffWeReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer,0,bytesRead);
```

**But my problem is, sometimes I receive data out of order.**  And I stress the word sometimes.  In my test, I had 5 iPads running my application side by side, and was sending all 5 ipads the same exact data.  99.9% of the time they receive the data correctly and in the right order, but 0.1% of the time ONE iPad will receive data out of order.

[I was told in this post, that Data should never come out of order... Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong to trigger this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992248/asynchronous-client-socket-increasing-the-buffer-size)

Here is a console output example of data that is in the correct order:

[image]
[Link to above picture](http://i88.photobucket.com/albums/k194/lampshade9909/Screen1_zpsb996c5d5.jpg)

[image]
[Link to above picture](http://i88.photobucket.com/albums/k194/lampshade9909/Screen2_zps330a6dd2.jpg)

I know the python script on the server that is sending the data is sending data correctly because, as I mentioned above, in my test I have 5 iPads running the application and only 1 iPad will have this problem (this problem only happens a fraction of a percentage of the time...)

I am staring my Asynchronous Client Socket in a background thread as seen below:

```
    AsyncClient_Thread = new Thread(() => AsyncClient.StartClient());
    AsyncClient_Thread.IsBackground = true;
    AsyncClient_Thread.Start();


    public void StartClient()
    {
        // Connect to a remote device.
        try {
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.                

            string ipAddress = appDel.wallInteractionScreen.Host_WallServer;
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), port);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            ClientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect to the remote endpoint.
            ClientSocket.BeginConnect( remoteEP, 
                new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), ClientSocket);
            connectDone.WaitOne();

            Receive(ClientSocket);
            receiveDone.WaitOne();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in AsyncClient StartClient: ");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }

        //          Console.WriteLine("Finished StartClient");
    }
```

Here is my ReceiveCallback function

```
    private static void ReceiveCallback( IAsyncResult ar )
    {
        AppDelegate appDel = (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;

        // I added this InvokeOnMainThread to see if it would solve the "data out of order problem", but it didn't
        appDel.InvokeOnMainThread (delegate{
            Console.WriteLine("ReceiveCallback IsMainThread = " + NSThread.IsMain);

            try {
                // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
                // from the asynchronous state object.
                StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
                Socket client = state.workSocket;

                // Read data from the remote device.
                int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

                if (bytesRead > 0) {
                    // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                    string stuffWeReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer,0,bytesRead);

                    string debugString = "~~ReceiveCallback~~ len = " + stuffWeReceived.Length + " bytesRead = " + bytesRead + ": " + stuffWeReceived;
                    if ( appDel.diagnosticsScreen.DebugAsyncReceiveBuffer_Switch.On )
                    {
                        appDel.diagnosticsScreen.AppendToDebugLog(debugString);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(debugString);


                    // Send this data to be received
                    appDel.wallInteractionScreen.ChitterChatter.ReceiveSomeData(stuffWeReceived);

                    // Get the rest of the data.
                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer,0,StateObject.BufferSize,0,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                } else {
                    // Signal that all bytes have been received.
                    receiveDone.Set();
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine("Error in AsyncClient ReceiveCallback: ");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: First things first: have you isolated whether it was *received* out of order vs whether it was *sent* out of order? is there any remote chance that the python script is messing up the send? or is that obscenely simple?

Comment: Likewise: is there any chance that `ReceiveSomeData`, especially when multiple threads are involved, is not guaranteeing the order?

Comment: Just so I understand, this is C# code running on the IPAD? Is this on Mono or something?

Comment: I'm not 100% it was sent out of order, still trying to determine that.  The same message was sent to all 5 iPads and only 1 iPad shows it out of order.  In this test I was completely ignoring the result of the ReceiveSomeData function, I was testing the output from the appDel.diagnosticsScreen.AppendToDebugLog(debugString); And I called InvokeOnMainThread at the start of the ReceiveCallback.  This seems like it's a threading/timing issue but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm using Xamarin Studio & C#.

Comment: The process of sending the same message to all 5 iPads from the python script happens very quickly, I suppose it's possible that there is something causing it to send it correctly 4 times to 4 different iPads then out of order the 5th time.  I'm trying things on the python side now

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be running the entire callback on the UI thread; you only want to invoke onto the UI thread if you're updating UI elements.

Comment: I actually wasn't calling InvokeOnMainThread here before and was still having the same problem.  I put the InvokeOnMainThread in there just to test...

Comment: Run Wireshark on the server machine, capture the data exchange, and examine the logs. The log will show for sure if the problem is that you're sending bad data or if your recv code is broken.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a Threading/Locking problem in my code on the C# side.  I rewrote my locking mechanisms from scratch and now have things working 100% of the time.  Thanks to everyone who helped me see this one through!